# Skype for Business WebSDK for On premises environment

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

We are using Skype for Business 2015 in our Organization (On-premises environment).

We are trying to integrate Skype web features to the Intranet Web sites using Skype for business WebSDK. Internet connectivity/access are not allowed in my environment.

I tried downloading and running sample mentioned in below link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/gettingstarted#sectionSection4 
While evaluating I figured out that SkypeBootStrap.min.js is looking for sdk.js hosted in (https://latest-swx.cdn.skype.com/jLync/master_0.4.514/sdk.js)

Can you please suggest any alternate approach for running SkypeWebSDK samples?

My ultimate goal is to develop a reusable client-side component that can be integrated into any of our intranet web applications within our firm which provides all of Skype communication options (including audio, video and screen sharing) through a simple client-side API. What is the best way to achieve this?